# Using Azure LoadBalancerProbe to automatically reboot failed instance

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

Is it possible to use the cloud role (classic) LoadBalancerProbe with HTTPS Health probe to automatically restart a failed role instance?

I understand that this situation should be investigated, but if there's some spontaneous issue and all it needs is a reboot, and nobody is immediately aware of the issue (i.e. after hours or in a crisis), then it could resolve the situation.

Or at worst, can we tell it to move the existing connection to a health instance? Or will that happen when the user hits refresh on their browser?

Answer (score 0):

Service Healing feature should help in this case. It is already provided service in Azure. For both web and worker roles, Azure injects a guest agent into the VM to monitor your role. This guest agent also performs a health check every 15 seconds of the role instance in the virtual machine. Again, if a predefined number of consecutive health check failures or a signal from the load balancer causes a role to become unhealthy and a recovery action to be initiated which is to restart the role instance.

Ref : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/service-healing-auto-recovery-of-virtual-machines/

Comment: What about the comment "Note: This applies only in the case of the default GA based Load Balancer rotation and not custom LB probe."? If we're using the custom LB Probe then does this not work?